# What is the difference between assignment and overriding in a child class?

Tags: python

This has been bugging me for a while and appears hard to google.

In the following code can anyone explain the pragmatic difference between `FirstChild` and `SecondChild`.  It's clear from experiments that both *"work"* and arguably `SecondChild` is marginally more efficient.  But is there something that I'm missing about the way these two behave?  Are they different and *how* are they different?

```py
import collections


class Parent:

    def send_message(self, message: str):
        pass


class FirstChild(Parent):

    def __init__(self):
        self.message_queue = collections.deque()

    def send_message(self, message: str):
        self.message_queue.append(message)


class SecondChild(Parent):

    def __init__(self):
        self.message_queue = collections.deque()
        self.send_message = self.message_queue.append
```

Comment: Fair enough. Read about the descriptor protocol and bound methods.

Comment: @MadPhysicist  Fair enough. No harm done ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FirstChild` creates a descriptor in the *class* called `send_message`. When you do `instance.send_message`, the interpreter first searches the instance `__dict__` for the name, then the class. When it's found in the class, the function is *bound* to the instance to create a method object that doesn't accept `self`. It happens every time you do the lookup, and it looks something like

```
method = type(instance).send_message.__get__(type(instance), instance)
```

`SecondChild` assigns a bound method as the attribute `send_message` in the *instance*. It cuts out the lookup in its own class object, as well as the lookup in the `deque` class object, and binding. That is probably why it appears marginally more efficient.

A major practical difference between these approaches is that `send_message` in `SecondChild` is not overridable. Since functions are non data descriptors (they have a `__get__` method but not `__set__` (and yes, functions have a class type and methods, like any other object)), the instance attribute `send_message` in `SecondChild` will always trump any class-level function. This means that a child of `SecondChild` that calls the parent `__init__` method will hide any implementation of `send_message` it creates.

You will likely find the official descriptor guide to be quite informative: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html